# What does a reader access to a resource really mean in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-resource-manager, rbac

What does a reader access to a resource really mean in Azure. For example, if the access to a Databricks workspace is reader, would the service principal with reader access be able to use that workspace?

And let us say, I want to allow a user to create containers in a storage resource, would it be fine, if I give that user reader access to the Resource group containing that storage resource, and contributor access to that storage resource?

I have read that RBAC is inherited from top. So, if I give reader access to a user for a resource group, it means for a resource in that resource group, the user would also have reader access. But can the RBAC for a resource then be overwritten, so that it is for example contributor for the resource, while still maintaining only reader access for the resource group?

Comment: So, with reader on Resource group, the user can not only view the list of the resources, but also use them, right?

Comment: With **`reader`** role, the user can only view but can't use it or modify it.

Comment: I mean, for example, there is a Resource Group 'TestRG' and in that Resource Group I have a storage resource 'TestStorage' and within that a container 'TestContainer'. If I give user A a reader access to 'TestRG', he would be able to use the 'TestContainer', right?  I mean he would be able to read from that container.

Comment: And if a user can only view resources with reader for a resource group but not use them, how can you allow users to use resources in such a resource group, but not create or modify any of those resources.

Comment: Please refer this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#reader) that describes what **`reader`** role does.

Comment: Well the document says, "View all resources, but does not allow you to make any changes". which is a very vague statement. It doesn't say whether you can still use the resources in a resource group or not.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what you mean by "use the resources in a resource group"?

Comment: Let us say I create a Databricks workspace "TestDB" in a Resource group "TestRG". And I assign user A reader access to "TestRG". Would user A only be able to see "TestDB" or could he also login and use that workspace (providing of course I add the user A as a user in that workspace).

Comment: AFAIK, the user can only see but can't use the workspace.

Comment: ok, so what step should we take to make the user be able to use that workspace? If I give contributor access to "TestRG", then the user could also create resources in that Resource Group "TestRG". So, basically what needs to be done to allow the user to use that databricks workspace "TestDB", but not create any by himself in the resource group "TestRG"?

Answer (score 1):

***I tested the same scenario in my environment and got the below results:***

I assigned **`reader`** role to a user for resource group and **`contributor`** role for storage account like below:

[image]

If you give **`reader`** role access to a user for a resource group, the user can only view the list of resource groups but can't create or modify the resource groups.

***When the user attempts to create a resource group with **`reader`** role he will get error like below:***

[image: ![enter image description here](https://i.imgur.com/MU8Y9MO.png)]

If the user has **`contributor`** role on particular resource like storage account, he gains access only on that storage account and can manage it like creating containers, deleting blobs etc.

Please **note** that if the user has multiple roles on a particular resource/subscription, the role with **higher privileges** overlaps the remaining roles based on the hierarchy.

In the above scenario, even the resource group has **`reader`** role and the storage account has **`contributor`** role it overlaps **`reader`** role.

***Hierarchy based on higher privileges to lower privileges are like below:***

*Owner (High) -> Contributor -> Reader -> User Access Administrator (Low)*

For more in detail, please **refer** below links:

[What is Azure role-based access control (Azure RBAC)? | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview#multiple-role-assignments)

[Classic subscription administrator roles, Azure roles, and Azure AD roles | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/rbac-and-directory-admin-roles?context=%2Fazure%2Factive-directory%2Froles%2Fcontext%2Fugr-context#azure-roles)